# System of higher order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Sorry asking out of interest but is it possible for there to be a system of ODEs
like

$X'' + X' = AX$

if so could one give an example of system which could be represented
 as this

Comment: What do you mean? To find a specific example with a speficit matrix $\mathbf A$ studied in literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf A = (a_{ij})_{ij} $ and if $\mathbf X = [x_1,\dots,x_n]^{\text{T}}$, we can write your system as

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1'' + x_1 ' = a_{11}x_1 + \dots + a_{1n}x_n \\
x_2'' + x_2 ' = a_{21}x_1 + \dots + a_{2n}x_n \\
\vdots
\\
x_n'' + x_n ' = a_{n1}x_1 + \dots + a_{nn}x_n \\
\end{cases}
$$

For example, if $n=2$ and $\mathbf  A = \operatorname{Id}$, we get

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1''+x_1' = x_1\\
x_2'' +x_2' = x_2
\end{cases}
$$

which has solution

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}t(1+\sqrt 5)} +c_2 \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}t(1-\sqrt 5)} \\
c_3 \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}t(1+\sqrt 5)} +c_4 \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}t(1-\sqrt 5)} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Calling $X = X_1, \dot X_1 = X_2$ we have

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot X_1\\ \dot X_2\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & I\\ A & -I\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}X_1\\ X_2\end{array}\right)
$$